# Google Chrome anti-virus checks take too long for downloads from our site. Can it be bypassed or sped up?

Tags: security, google-chrome, download, virus

I host a windows software website. I noticed that new version of Google Chrome checks downloaded files presumably for viruses and it takes about 10-20 seconds to complete.

Is there any way to white list our software to bypass that check or make it faster? The file is about 49 MB in size.

Comment: Does it happen in incognito mode? Could be an extensions issue or a user profile issue. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/sUs1cwmmpLk

Comment: Also does it happen on a different computer (preferably with a different OS)? It might be your antivirus software that is holding up Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended making a web installer - a small app that downloads and run full installer, similar to installer of Google Chrome itself. That web installer is just 600kb in size and this solved the problem for us.